# socket.io in Svelte via store

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io, svelte

I'd like to have `socket.io` available across the whole `Svelte` app. I don't know what I am doing wrong...

**store.js**

```js
export const socket = writable();
```

## This works

**App.svelte**

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { socket } from "./stores.js";

$socket = io();

$socket.on("orders", (orders) => {
    console.log(orders);
});
```

## This doesn't

**App.svelte**

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { socket } from "./stores.js";

$socket = io();
```

**Component.svelte**

```js
import { socket } from "./stores.js";

$socket.on("orders", (orders) => {
    console.log(orders);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown works as long as the execution order is guaranteed to be correct, i.e. the code in `App` running before the code in `Component`.

If it is not, you need to add additional logic to handle the store not being set. (You also probably should clean up these `on` event handlers via [`onDestroy`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-ondestroy) as well.)

E.g. you can use a [reactive statement](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive) to check whether the store was set, if it is initialized with `null`:

```js
$: if ($socket != null) {
    $socket.on("orders", (orders) => {
        console.log(orders);
    });
}
```